# I need add decimal last 3 of number

Tags: python

I have problem write with python language to add decimal places in last 3 of number.
Example: I have batch number 12340000

Expected Result : 12340.000

Comment: So... you want to divide by 1000?

Comment: Where is your own attempt at solving the problem?

Comment: `s = f'{12340000/1000:.03f}'`?

Comment: You can do this by string manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = 12340000
a = "{:.3f}".format(a/1000)
```

Comment: Could you please provide some context behind this answer? As it stands this doesn't give other users much explanation as to how you came up with this solution.